# Get number of a contact

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, contacts

I develop c# in Xamarin and I trying to get the number of a contact. I tried like this:

```
    private static int PICK_NUMAR = 1;

    private void Click (object sender , EventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent (Intent.ActionPick , Android.Net.Uri.Parse ("content://contacts"));
            intent.SetType (ContactsContract.Contacts.ContentType);
            StartActivityForResult (intent , SMS_Send.PICK_NUMAR);
        }
    protected override void OnActivityResult (int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        if ((requestCode == SMS_Send.PICK_NUMAR) && (resultCode == Result.Ok) && (data != null)) {

            Android.Net.Uri uri = data.Data;
            string[] projection = new [] { ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.Number };

            using (Android.Database.ICursor c = ManagedQuery (uri, projection, null, null, null)) {
                if (c != null) {
                    string NUMAR_TELEFON = c.GetString (c.GetColumnIndex (ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.Number));
                    c.MoveToFirst ();
                    FindViewById<EditText> (Resource.Id.Input2).Text = NUMAR_TELEFON;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

But didn't work. I tried to debug and I saw that the code stuck after the declaration of ICursor. What I've done wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The [Xamarin Mobile](https://components.xamarin.com/view/xamarin.mobile) component has a simplified API for accessing the Contacts on both Android and iOS (note that Android requires the `READ_CONTACTS` permission in the Manifest)

```
using Xamarin.Contacts;
// ...

var book = new AddressBook (this);

if (!await book.RequestPermission()) {
    Console.WriteLine ("Permission denied by user or manifest");
    return;
}

foreach (Contact contact in book.OrderBy (c => c.LastName)) {
    Console.WriteLine ("{0} {1}", contact.FirstName, contact.LastName);
}
```